# how to display two different warning message by oninvalid

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<input type="text"
  id="usr" 
  name="usr"
  placeholder="Student ID"
  pattern="/^[0-9]+.?[0-9]*$/"
  oninvalid = "if (this.value!=''){this.setCustomValidity('Number')}"
  required
  oninvalid = "alert('please input the username')"
>
```

I want to check if the input is null or number

My code seems to not work

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to separate out your inline JS and then you can use the [custom validity methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/setCustomValidity).

Note: the value of the `pattern` attribute doesn't require the close and end `/`.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', handleInput);

function handleInput() {
  const { patternMismatch, valueMissing } = this.validity;
  if (!this.value.length) this.setCustomValidity('');
  if (!patternMismatch || !valueMissing) this.setCustomValidity('');
  if (patternMismatch || valueMissing) {
    this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid student ID');
  }
  this.reportValidity();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="usr"  name="usr" placeholder="Student ID" pattern="^[0-9]+(\.?[0-9]*)$" required />
```